# Swiftui TextField onkeypress

Tags: uitextfield, swiftui

I've to call a function when the user write on TextField (onkeypress), 
how I create it in swiftui? I've to call an api for a Search function.
thanks.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60722806/observing-binding-or-state-variables/60724483#60724483

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `Binding` and make your api call there

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text = ""

    var body: some View {
        let binding = Binding(
            get: { self.text },
            set: {
                self.text = $0
                print($0)
                // Add call to API here
            }
        )

        return TextField("Test", text: binding)
    }
}
```